# Creating a function in R to search through and remove data given an NA

Tags: r, function, search, data.table, na

I was given four bars of printed ink. I measured all four bars and got what the color components of each are. I'm trying to determine and show whether the gray bars being between the target values indicates that the solid bars are going to be in spec. The given is that the gray bar is between target values. If it is not, then I want to remove the corresponding values for that sample/zone/color. Here is a snippet of the data:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(data.table)

testDT <- data.table(structure(list(Zone = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L,6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L,8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L,6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L,8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L,6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L,8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L),
                                    Data = c(0.62, 0.27, 0.35, 0.95, 0.62,0.26, 0.35, 0.95, 0.64, 0.27, 0.36, 0.96, 0.64, 0.27, 0.37, 0.95,0.64, 0.27, 0.38, 0.96, 0.64, 0.27, 0.38, 0.96, 0.65, 0.27, 0.38,0.99, 0.68, 0.27, 0.38, 0.99, 0.61, 0.3, 0.91, 0.51, 0.61, 0.3,0.91, 0.51, 0.63, 0.3, 0.93, 0.52, 0.63, 0.3, 0.94, 0.52, 0.66,0.3, 0.97, 0.52, 0.67, 0.3, 0.99, 0.52, 0.66, 0.29, 0.99, 0.54,0.67, 0.29, 1.01, 0.54, 0.61, 0.79, 0.69, 0.37, 0.61, 0.79, 0.7,0.37, 0.62, 0.78, 0.71, 0.38, 0.62, 0.79, 0.72, 0.38, 0.63, 0.75,0.75, 0.38, 0.63, 0.76, 0.76, 0.38, 0.62, 0.72, 0.76, 0.39, 0.63,0.73, 0.78, 0.39),
                                    Bar = structure(c(2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L,3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L,3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L,3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L,3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L,3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L,3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L),
                                        .Label = c("Cyan", "Gray","Magenta", "Yellow"), class = "factor"), SampleID = c(6L, 6L,6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L,6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L,6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L,6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L,6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L,6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L),
                                    Color = structure(c(1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L,3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                                        .Label = c("Cyan","Magenta", "Yellow"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Zone","Data", "Bar", "SampleID", "Color"), sorted = "Color", class = c("data.table","data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -96L)), key='Color')
```

The target values for the gray bars are 0.55 to 0.65. Basically, I just want to remove the data from the solid bars that correspond to data not in the target for the gray bars by zone.

So my approach is that I'll first find out which sample, zone, and colors do fall between the values for the gray bar. That code is as follows:

```
testDT2 <- testDT[Bar == "Gray"]
testDT2 <- testDT2[Color != "Visual"]
ranges <- data.table(Color = c("Cyan","Magenta","Yellow"), low  = c(0.55,0.55,0.55), high = c(0.65,0.65,0.65)); ranges
`%okDen%` <- function(x = test, vals1 = low, vals2 = high) x >= vals1 & x <= vals2
`%NotOkDen%` <- Negate(`%okDen%`)
setkeyv(ranges,'Color'); setkeyv(testDT2,'Color')
testDT2 <- merge(testDT2, ranges, all.x = TRUE); testDT2
testDT2 <- testDT2[`%NotOkDen%`(Data, low, high), Data := NA]

testDT1 <- testDT[Bar != "Gray"]
testDT1 <- testDT1[Color != "Visual"]
```

Now, I need to create a function that will cherry pick the values that are now NA’s and remove the corresponding values from the colored bar data.

For example: Gray bar sample 7, zone 8 for cyan is not within the required values and is thus given an NA. I want to create a function to see that and then go find the data for the cyan bar, cyan color, for sample 7 in zone 8 and list it as NA.

Would anyone be able to help me create such a function? I have no idea where to go.

Comment: @Arun, if you look at `testDT1`, you can see that it has a list of data points for the colored bars. They have all the same columns as the one for the gray bars. Basically, I want a function to; see where the NA's are in `testDT2`; look at the zone, sample number, and color listed for that point in `testDT2`; find the colored bar in `testDT1` that matches the color, zone, and sample number from `testDT2`; and finally change the Data entry to NA.

Comment: @Arun lemme start from scratch. I was given four bars of printed ink. I measured all four bars and got what the color components of each are. I'm trying to determine and show whether the gray bars being between the target values indicates that the solid bars are going to be in spec. The given is that the gray bar is between target values. If it is not, then I want to remove the corresponding values for that sample/zone/color from the colored bars. I updated my question to reflect this. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All credit for this goes to @Arun.

```
testDT[testDT[, .I[Data[Bar == "Gray"] %between% c(0.55, 0.65)], list(Zone, SampleID, Color)]$V1]
```